# Backing up Kafka in a Non Idempotent Architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, backup, event-sourcing

We're heading up the architecture of an event sourced solution leveraging both Kafka Streams and vanilla Kafka topic consuming/producing of messages. The "workers" are not idempotent but we are instead relying on consumer groups offsets. Kafka [acts as our single source of truth](https://www.confluent.io/blog/messaging-single-source-truth/).

Looking through options for true backup (i.e., replication is not backup) solutions for Kafka we've seen the variety of S3 connectors out there, and did check out Confluent's Replicator as well as the coming MirrorMaker 2. None do – to my knowledge – offer true protection in terms of topic deletion nor point-in-time restoration.

As a small-ish startup, we're keen on not operating Kafka in house, albeit disk level snapshots (not offered by any actor known to me) seems to be the way forward.

Having looked at AWS MSK, Confluent and CloudKarafka I am interested in hearing about your experiences, pros/cons and solutions in a similar (or at least approximate) architectures...

Comment: Did you evaluated portworx kafka ....https://docs.portworx.com/portworx-install-with-kubernetes/application-install-with-kubernetes/kafka-with-zookeeper/#portworx-storageclass-for-volume-provisioning

Comment: MM2 should offer "point in time" based on the fact that you can seek to an offset at a particular time (given its still retained). Preventing topic deletion can be solved by proper ACLs. Otherwise, you would need to look at taking snapshots of your disks